# ValueError: Expected input batch_size (1) to match target batch_size (100). Tried but in vain

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a deep learning model with SVHN dataset. I took the tutorial of MNIST model and done with SVHN model

Code:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torchsummary import summary
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision.datasets import SVHN
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import DataLoader
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

def train(train_loader,model,accuracies,losses):
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # Forward pass
        images=to_device(images)
        labels=to_device(labels)
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        
        # Backward pass and optimization
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
    acc = (predicted == labels).sum().item() / labels.size(0)
    accuracies.append(acc)
    losses.append(loss.item())
    return loss,acc,accuracies,losses
        
def validate(val_loader,model,val_accuracies,val_losses):
    val_loss = 0.0
    val_acc = 0.0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for images, labels in val_loader:
            images=to_device(images)
            labels=to_device(labels)
            outputs = model(images)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            val_loss += loss.item()
            
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total = labels.size(0)
        correct = (predicted == labels).sum().item()
        val_acc += correct / total
        val_accuracies.append(val_acc)
        val_losses.append(loss.item())
        return val_loss,val_acc,val_accuracies,val_losses
    

def to_device(a):
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    a.to(device)
    return a

def evaluate(model,test_loader):
    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        correct = 0
        total = 0
        y_true = []
        y_pred = []
        for images, labels in test_loader:
            images = to_device(images)
            labels = to_device(labels)
            outputs = model(images)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
            predicted=predicted.to('cpu')
            labels=labels.to('cpu')
            y_true.extend(labels)
            y_pred.extend(predicted)

    print('\nTest Accuracy: {}%'.format(100 * correct / total))

    print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))


import torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Classifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout2d(0.25)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout2d(0.5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(409600, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x2=self.conv1(x)
        x1=F.relu(x2)
        x = self.pool(x1)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1)
        x = x.view(-1, 409600)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        print(x.shape)
        return x

transform_one_channel = transforms.Compose([
                                transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),                              
                                transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize([0.5,],[0.5,])
                                ])

test_dataset=SVHN(root="E:/git/Door_number_finding_system/data",split='test', download=True, transform=transform_one_channel)
train_dataset=SVHN(root="E:/git/Door_number_finding_system/data", download=True, transform=transform_one_channel)

model = Classifier()
model=to_device(model)
summary(model, (1, 640, 640))

batch_size=100
num_epochs=10


val_percent = 0.2
val_size = int(val_percent * len(train_dataset))
train_size = len(train_dataset) - val_size
train_dataset, val_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(train_dataset,[train_size,val_size])

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True,pin_memory=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=False,pin_memory=True)

losses = []
accuracies = []
val_losses = []
val_accuracies = []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    loss,acc,accuracies,losses=train(train_loader,model,accuracies,losses)
    val_loss,val_acc,val_accuracies,val_losses=validate(val_loader,model,val_accuracies,val_losses)
```

Whereas my output error is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[199], line 2
      1 for epoch in range(num_epochs):
----> 2     loss,acc,accuracies,losses=train(train_loader,model,accuracies,losses)
      3     val_loss,val_acc,val_accuracies,val_losses=validate(val_loader,model,val_accuracies,val_losses)
      5     print('Epoch [{}/{}] - Loss:{:.4f}, Validation Loss:{:.4f}, Accuracy:{:.2f}, Validation Accuracy:{:.2f}'.format(
      6         epoch+1, num_epochs, loss.item(), val_loss/100, acc ,val_acc))

Cell In[189], line 10, in train(train_loader, model, accuracies, losses)
      8 labels=to_device(labels)
      9 outputs = model(images)
---> 10 loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
     12 # Backward pass and optimization
     13 optimizer.zero_grad()

File c:\Users\Sanmitha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File c:\Users\Sanmitha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py:1174, in CrossEntropyLoss.forward(self, input, target)
   1173 def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
-> 1174     return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
   1175                            ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction,
   1176                            label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)

File c:\Users\Sanmitha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:3029, in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   3027 if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3028     reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3029 return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)

ValueError: Expected input batch_size (1) to match target batch_size (100).
```

Where I'm going wrong? There may be few changes that needs to be made when converting a model with MNIST dataset to SVHN dataset. By in my view, everything is fine. I convert the RGB image to Grey Scale image in order to fit the model.